# CSS3 Button Animation Ruined When Adding Directory

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML 5 and CSS3 script with a fancy button which when pressed does a CSS Animation, But only when it has no directory. When I add a redirect the site immediately loads up ignoring the animation given to the button. How can I add a re-direct to the button and have the CSS Animation play completely before the site loads the new page

```
        <!DOCUTYPE html>
    <html lang="En">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--CREDITS-->
    <meta name="Developer" content="Elitezen">
    <meta name="Language(s)" content="HTML5 , CSS3 , JS">
    <meta name="Software" content="anWriter">
    <!-- END CREDITS -->
    <head>
       <title> Elitezen Website Test | Login Page </title>
    <style>
    html {
          background-image: url('http://image.downloadwap.co.uk/wallpapers/wp/18/nature/maligne-st_pJi7nPeU.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          min-height: 100%;
          background-size: cover;

    }

    h1 {
        color:#ffffff;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    #Login{
           /*VISUALS*/
           padding-left:20px;
           padding-right:20px;
           padding-top:10px;
           padding-bottom:10px;
           background-color:#0095f0;
           border:none;
           color:#ffffff;
           font-weight:bold;
           border-radius:4px;
           display: inline-block;
           /*POSITION*/
           position: absolute;
           top: 400px;
           right: 135px;
           /*Metrics*/
           font-size:20px;
                               /*ANIMATION*/
          transition: all 0.5s;
          cursor: pointer;
          margin: 5px;
          }

    #Login span {
                 cursor: pointer;
                 display: inline-block;
                 position: relative;
                 transition: 0.5s;
                 }

    #Login span:after {
                       content: '\00bb';
                       position: absolute;
                       opacity: 0;
                       top : 0;
                       right: -20px;
                       transition: 0.5s;
                       }

    #Login:hover span {
                       padding-right: 25px;
                       }

    #Login:hover span:after {
                             opacity: 1;
                             right: 0;
    }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 align="center">Welcome! <br /> Please Sign In...</h1>
    <form action="Oofio.html">
    <button id="Login" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <span>
    Login
    </button>
    </span>
    </form>

    <script>

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with: 'But only when it has no directory'? When ou click the button i think you submit the form to the oofio.html page. To prevent this you can use js.

Comment: By that I the Animation only loads when there&#39;s no link to execute when the button is clicked, sorry for the confusion

Comment: when the action attribute for the form is empty you want to start the animation ?

Comment: Well I want the Animation to play fully before it goes to the link

Answer (score 0):

If i Understand:
When you click to the Button whid id=Login you want to play your css animation and then submit the form.
So One solution is use jQuery to delay the submission of the form.

```
$('#Login').on('click',function(){ 
    //do something  
    event.preventDefault(); 
    setTimeout( function () { 
        $(form).submit();
    }, 300); //submit starts after 300ms
})
```